# App_Code class not being recognized

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a bunch of classes under my `App_Code` folder. Everything was working fine.

Just recently, I added another class and it's not being picked up where I want to use it, in other words `"The name '_DocumentsBLL' does not exist in the current context"`. `_DocumentsBLL` being the name of my class.

There are no namespace conflicts as I can access all the other classes under `App_Code` except that one.

Comment: Make sure it is public.

Comment: @MairajAhmad Its public

Comment: The error message states `_DocumentsBLL` (with underscore) but later you write `DocumentsBLL` (without underscore) — which one is correct?

Comment: @OndrejTucny Sorry, typo error, i have corrected it

Comment: Make sure `Build Action` is set to `Compile` on `File Properties`.

Comment: Awesome @AndersonPimentel It worked. Can you write it as an answer so I mark it an answer?

Comment: `_DocumentsBLL` does not follow the C# naming standards. It should be `DocumentsBll`. No, it didn't cause your problem, but it's important to follow naming standards when other people view your code.

Comment: @MunasheTsododo Done! Already happened to me. That's the kind of problem that drives you crazy. =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `Build Action` is set to `Compile` on `File Properties`.